# Search file from .csv in all subfolders and copy it to new location

Tags: bash, shell

I have .csv file containing 3 columns. I want to extract names of '.tif' files from 2nd column of .csv file. Search those names for image files stored in different subfolders of the folder_A and copy all these files to the folder_B.
I want to do it with shell script. Any help?

```
instance_identifier,Image_name,therapeutic_class
DMSO_0_26247_p12_ER_s4,cdp2w9x2_p12_s4_w2e7e45247-7535-47c6-9125-62c2ecb0f440.tif,control
DMSO_0_26247_p12_ER_s5,cdp2w9x2_p12_s5_w2f724ded3-24a8-466a-b578-539f79140a8b.bmp,control
DMSO_0_26247_p12_ER_s6,cdp2w9x2_p12_s6_w2794d1ed4-bbb9-4790-b082-324ad7dc8438.tif,control
DMSO_0_26247_p12_Mito_s1,cdp2w9x2_p12_s1_w5b288b243-7189-41f0-993e-4444faac5197.png,control
DMSO_0_26247_p12_Mito_s2,cdp2w9x2_p12_s2_w522e6faa1-729a-4272-b476-4ec27d3459ca.tif,control
```

I tried something like this ,but I couldn't specify .tif files and didn't succed

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=',', read -r instance_identifier Image_name therapeutic_class;
do
    echo "$Image_name"
    find /folder_A/ -name "${Image_name}" -exec cp '{}' /folder_B \;
done < image_exp_details.csv
```

Comment: You have `IFS=','` but your example data seems to be space delimited

Comment: Are you using GNU `cp`?  If so, use `-exec cp -t /folder_B {} +` (with quotes around the braces and plus if you prefer, but they aren't necessary).  That copies all the files to the target directory in one command.  It may not help much here, but it can be helpful in other contexts.

Comment: In my actual file which has millions of lines does contains ','. I couldn't upload my .csv file so my apology

Comment: You should show the first 4 lines or so of the file...as it really is so as not to mislead.  If there are commas in it, you should at least show the commas.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler how will i specify only .tif files?

Comment: To select specific file types, the old-fashioned way: `case "$header2" in (*.tif) …process tif file…;; esac`.  You could probably use `[[ … ]]` with a regex match as well.  Another way is with `find /folder_A/ -name "${header2}" -a -name '*.tif' -exec cp -t /folder_B {} +`.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being dense... where is `header2` being assigned?

Comment: @PaulHodges: The example material original had `read -r header1 header2 header3`; it has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to filter lines containing `.tif` in column 2:

```
$ cat /tmp/file
# Table looks like
#header1   header2   header3
#name1     aa1.jpg    positive
#name2     aa2.tif    positive
#name3     aa3.bmp    negative
#name4     aa4.tif    positive
#name5     aa5.tif    negative

$ awk '$2~/\.tif$/' /tmp/file 
#name2     aa2.tif    positive
#name4     aa4.tif    positive
#name5     aa5.tif    negative
```

---

Given the updated input:

```
$ awk -F, '$2~/\.tif$/{print $2}' /tmp/file
cdp2w9x2_p12_s4_w2e7e45247-7535-47c6-9125-62c2ecb0f440.tif
cdp2w9x2_p12_s6_w2794d1ed4-bbb9-4790-b082-324ad7dc8438.tif
cdp2w9x2_p12_s2_w522e6faa1-729a-4272-b476-4ec27d3459ca.tif
```

Comment: You can use that `awk` to feed the Bash while loop -- you have it.

Comment: I am not a programmer. Important part for me is to search these terms and find images, copy them to new location.

Answer (score 0):

`grep`/`xargs` will run it faster if there are so many records.

```
grep -Eo '[^,]+[.]tif' image_exp_details.csv | 
  xargs -IFileName find -name FileName -exec mv {} /folder_B/ \;
```

This may needs some path tweaking. It will need to be run from `/folder_A/` with a full path to `image_exp_details.csv` if it isn't in `/folder_A/`.

I assume you ONLY want TIFF's listed in the CSV and that there are other you don't want moved, yes?

Comment: It will also generate a log to stderr of any files not found, which might be of value to you.

Comment: thanks paul, in first place I just gave general example thus I used header2 but thats now corrected. I am getting error that no such file exist. The solution you suggested doesn't search inside many subfolders of folder_A

Comment: Ah, subfolders - ok, hang on.

Comment: maybe stick an `echo` in front of the `mv` for a test run first. :)

Comment: it didn't moved any image to destination folder. Would you please explain me suggested command? what 'xargs -IFileName' will do?